# Algebraic transformation of expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

I have

```
AA = ((4 \[Beta]^2 \[Eta]\[Alpha])/(
F \[Gamma]^5 (\[Eta]\[Alpha] + \[Eta]\[Beta])) + (
4 \[Beta]^2 \[Eta]\[Beta])/(
F \[Gamma]^5 (\[Eta]\[Alpha] + \[Eta]\[Beta])) - (
2 \[Eta]\[Beta])/(
F \[Gamma]^3 (\[Eta]\[Alpha] + \[Eta]\[Beta])) - (
4 \[Beta]^2 \[Eta]\[Alpha]^2 \[Eta]\[Beta])/(
F \[Gamma]^3 (\[Eta]\[Alpha] + \[Eta]\[Beta])) - (
4 \[Eta]\[Beta]^2)/(
F \[Gamma]^3 \[Eta]\[Alpha] (\[Eta]\[Alpha] + \[Eta]\[Beta])) - (
12 \[Beta]^2 \[Eta]\[Alpha] \[Eta]\[Beta]^2)/(
F \[Gamma]^3 (\[Eta]\[Alpha] + \[Eta]\[Beta])) + (
4 \[Beta]^2 \[Eta]\[Beta]^3)/(
F \[Gamma]^3 (\[Eta]\[Alpha] + \[Eta]\[Beta])) + (
2 \[Eta]\[Beta]^3)/(
 F \[Gamma] (\[Eta]\[Alpha] + \[Eta]\[Beta])) + (
 4 \[Beta]^2 \[Eta]\[Alpha]^2 \[Eta]\[Beta]^3)/(
 F \[Gamma] (\[Eta]\[Alpha] + \[Eta]\[Beta])));

  BB = (4 \[Beta]^2)/(\[Gamma] F) (-((\[Eta]\[Beta] (2 \[Eta]\[Alpha]^2 \
  + 1/\[Beta]^2))/(\[Gamma]^2 \[Eta]\[Alpha]) + (
 2 \[Eta]\[Alpha]^2 \[Eta]\[Beta])/(\[Gamma]^2 \
   \[Eta]\[Alpha])) + ((\[Eta]\[Beta] (\[Eta]\[Beta]^2 + 
  1/\[Gamma]^2) (2 \[Eta]\[Alpha]^2 + 2/\[Gamma]^2 + 
  1/\[Beta]^2))/(
   2 (\[Eta]\[Alpha] + \[Eta]\[Beta])) + (\[Eta]\[Alpha] (2 \
    \[Eta]\[Alpha] \[Eta]\[Beta] + \[Eta]\[Beta]^2 + 
  1/\[Gamma]^2))/(\[Gamma]^2 (\[Eta]\[Alpha] + \
    \[Eta]\[Beta]))));


AA == BB // FullSimplify
```

They are equal, but I don't know how to go from `A` to `B` using Mathematica. Your help is highly appreciated.

P.S. I want to go from `A` to `B` only not vice versa.

---

Sorry, there was a typo; the correct values are:

```
AA = ((4 \[Beta]^2 \[Eta]\[Alpha])/(
F \[Gamma]^5 (\[Eta]\[Alpha] + \[Eta]\[Beta])) + (
4 \[Beta]^2 \[Eta]\[Beta])/(
F \[Gamma]^5 (\[Eta]\[Alpha] + \[Eta]\[Beta])) - (
2 \[Eta]\[Beta])/(
F \[Gamma]^3 (\[Eta]\[Alpha] + \[Eta]\[Beta])) - (
4 \[Beta]^2 \[Eta]\[Alpha]^2 \[Eta]\[Beta])/(
F \[Gamma]^3 (\[Eta]\[Alpha] + \[Eta]\[Beta])) - (
4 \[Eta]\[Beta]^2)/(
F \[Gamma]^3 \[Eta]\[Alpha] (\[Eta]\[Alpha] + \[Eta]\[Beta])) - (
12 \[Beta]^2 \[Eta]\[Alpha] \[Eta]\[Beta]^2)/(
F \[Gamma]^3 (\[Eta]\[Alpha] + \[Eta]\[Beta])) + (
4 \[Beta]^2 \[Eta]\[Beta]^3)/(
F \[Gamma]^3 (\[Eta]\[Alpha] + \[Eta]\[Beta])) + (
2 \[Eta]\[Beta]^3)/(
F \[Gamma] (\[Eta]\[Alpha] + \[Eta]\[Beta])) + (
4 \[Beta]^2 \[Eta]\[Alpha]^2 \[Eta]\[Beta]^3)/(
F \[Gamma] (\[Eta]\[Alpha] + \[Eta]\[Beta])));

 BB = (4 \[Beta]^2)/(\[Gamma] F) (-((\[Eta]\[Beta] (2 \[Eta]\[Alpha]^2 \
    + 1/\[Beta]^2))/(\[Gamma]^2 \[Eta]\[Alpha]) + (
     2 \[Eta]\[Alpha]^2 \[Eta]\[Beta])/(\[Gamma]^2 \
       \[Eta]\[Alpha])) + ((\[Eta]\[Beta] (\[Eta]\[Beta]^2 + 
      1/\[Gamma]^2) (2 \[Eta]\[Alpha]^2 + 2/\[Gamma]^2 + 
      1/\[Beta]^2))/(
       2 (\[Eta]\[Alpha] + \[Eta]\[Beta])) + (\[Eta]\[Alpha] (2 \
   \[Eta]\[Alpha] \[Eta]\[Beta] + \[Eta]\[Beta]^2 + 
      1/\[Gamma]^2))/(\[Gamma]^2 (\[Eta]\[Alpha] + \
        \[Eta]\[Beta]))));


    AA == BB // FullSimplify
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure `A` and `B` are equal under all values of the variables? My attempt to prove their equality failed.

Comment: @m_goldberg Even stronger statement: They cannot be equivalent. As rational functions, if they were equivalent the `Together`d difference would have to be zero. Which it is not.

Comment: There was a typo and been corrected.